# Appending text and continuing progrees bar in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a code to print progress bar like :  `===========>`

Code snippet:

```
def run(self):
    event = self.event
    bar = '>'
    sys.stdout.write(bar)
    while not event.is_set():
        bar = "=".join(["", bar])
        sys.stdout.write(bar)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        event.wait(1)
```

This is always returning `>=>==>===>====>`  So basically it is printing > then => , ==> ...

How do I get the progress bar output like `=============>`

Comment: Why are you using stdout.write instead of print?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return to the beginning of the line using `\r` and overwrite it, e.g.:

```
import time
import sys

bar = '>'
for i in range(100):
    bar = '='.join(['', bar])
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + bar)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is becuase you are starting bar with ">" instead of adding in the end, this should work like you want it to, plus you dont really need bar:

```
def run(self):
event = self.event
while not event.is_set():
    sys.stdout.write("=")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    event.wait(1)
sys.stdout.write(">")
```

Comment: But this will print '>' at the end after printing all '=' . Can't we move > along with =   ?